# no scroll bar when opened on a smaller window

Tags: html, css, browser, window

I'm having a problem with my website: Everything opens fine when the window size is the same as the background image or bigger, but when i open on a smaller window, there's no scroll bar so the footer disappears.

attached is an image of what happens with a small window:

[SMALL WINDOW](http://s5.postimg.org/n8md8i5p3/Screen_shot_2013_08_08_at_2_21_18_PM.png)

and

[THIS IS MY WEBSITE](http://www.tasteofbrazilkc.com)

Comment: your code or jsfiddle???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your footer is disappearing because the element `#footer` set with a fixed height of 835px. This is causing the footer to always be 835px from the top of the **browser window**. Once the window is sized less than 835px the footer is no longer visible.

In order to keep the footer visible, try changing position to `absolute` instead of `fixed`. This will position the footer 835px from the top, relative to the top of the webpage itself, not the browser window.

To guarantee the footer will always be visible on any size screen, you could also apply `min-height: 835px;` to your body tag.

**EDIT**

Too keep your footer centered while using absolute positioning, try using a combination of `left` and `margin-left`. The style below will keep your footer centered, regardless of window size.

```
#footer {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; /* Always display footer 50% left of the screen width. */
  margin-left: -446px; /* -(Total footer width / 2) I.E. -(892px / 2) = -446px; */
  top: 835px;
  font-size: 14pt; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you trent. You solved one problem, but now there is another issue. The footer is always visible no matter what size of window the browser displays, however, when i resize the window, the footer (which is currently centered) moves to the left/right depending on the size of the window. How can I make sure the footer remains centered regardless of the window's size?

Comment: I've edited my answer above to include how to center your footer element. Thanks!